# Can someone explain me what is monero-blockchain-usage?

Tags: monerod, blockchain, blockchain-analysis, monero-blockchain-blackball, loglevel

How can I access the monero-blockchain-usage and what is the use of it ? could someone explain after input our db what should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

It's tallying up the counts of times outputs are used. You'll get logged lines which read:

```
M outputs used N times (P%)
```